# DirectoryServices два действующих пароля

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте, разработчики!

Пишу небольшую утилиту (`web-based`), которая позволяет пользователю сменить его пароль в `Active Directory` и еще несколько вкусностей.

Пользуюсь следующим кодом, для версии `.net 3.5`:

```
public static string ChPassword(string domain, string container, string userName, 
    string oldPassword, string newPassword)
{
    PrincipalContext principalContext =
        new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container,
            "admin", "password");
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
    if (user == null) 
        throw(new Exception("User Not Found In This Domain"));

    user.SetPassword(newPassword);
    user.Save(principalContext);
    return user.Name;
}
```

Собственно смена пароля работает, только после этой самой смены, работают оба пароля, и старый, и новый. Что для меня, в общем-то, странно.

Может, кто-то работал с данными библиотеками? Подскажите, пожалуйста, `best-practices` для решения моей проблемы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы далеко не первый кто с этим столкнулся :-)

Такое поведение связано с особенностями работы AD и Kerberos. В лучшем случае, старый пароль через некоторое время перестанет работать. Также, если пользователь входил в систему на какой-либо рабочей станции, там пароль кэшируется и в течение некоторого времени может быть использован для входа даже после изменения пароля в каталоге.

[Вот подробное описание](http://theruntime.com/blogs/devprime/archive/2009/04/16/old-passwords-still-working.aspx), почему так происходит

Comment: Спасибо. Позволил себе преобразовать в ответ.